# Salesforce Event Log for ApexExecution: cpu_time vs exec_time vs run_time

Tags: apex, performance, eventlogfile, event-monitoring

I'm currently working on an initiative to implement a Log Analysis tool for our organization to ingest the Platform/Logfile Event logs from Salesforce and be able to sort/analyze them over a longer period of time to help provide visibility into the performance of our application. We have a fully custom web application built on top of the Salesforce Experience Site that we are tracking.

**Question**: 
When looking into the ApexExecution event logs, I see 3 types of "execution time" fields.  The following information is what I have gathered from the Salesforce Documentation (that I could find) on these 3 fields.

- cpu_time //cpu time in milli to complete the request.  Indicates activity taking place at app server layer.
- exec_time //end to end apex execution in milli.
- run_time //amount of time request took in milli.

The issue I'm running into is these being quite different inside of one log file. I don't see anything in the documentation that really helps expand on what these are.

In one example I have

- cpu_time = 260
- exec_time = 373
- run_time = 2000

EDIT: Second example

- cpu_time = 5868
- exec_time = 3802
- run_time = 475495 (mind blown)

Now the cpu_time and exec_time I could understand just having 100 milliseconds difference.  cpu_time indicates it's at the app layer and exec_time indicates "end to end" apex execution which sounds like it would have maybe networking latency included?

What I don't get is the run_time being 4x the cpu_time. The definition of run_time doesn't really explain why it would be so much higher.

For the ApexExecution logs, I would not expect any value that measures "how long this took" to exceed the exec_time (end to end apex execution time) value.

Anyone have any insights on deeper explanations to these 3 values?

Comment: Here's the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile_apexexecution.htm). Note there are five values, not just these three, to interpret the log. DB_TOTAL_TIME and CALLOUT_TIME might fill in the gaps.

Comment: N.B. Products like SumoLogic have SFDC collectors for the event log, prebuilt dashboards, and a full query language for custom dashboards - plus, you can go back more than 30 days. Check your enterprise logging tool to see if you can avoid having to write custom code

Comment: @cropredy there's no custom code for this log analysis we're doing.  Our company has a custom web application built on top of salesforce.  We are monitoring that custom web application via the event logs.  We are using Datadog at this point.

Comment: @sfdcfox Thank you for pointing out DB_RUN_TIME.  It just says to compare to CPU_TIME to determine if it's your code or the db layer.   There is still no explanation of what run_time is.  We can make assumptions based on the data. CPU_TIME + DB_TOTAL_TIME is close to RUN_TIME.  But there is 0 documentation that backs that up, hence asking this question of the community.